# How to add table captions in MS Word using macros

Tags: vba, ms-word, macros, caption

I am trying to amend captions to 100 existing tables in MS Word. To avoid this tedious process I was hoping to use the built-in VB macro functionality.

If my table is inside the contents of the document in the section of:

1. Intro
   1.1 Goals

I want the table caption to be amended with "Intro - Goals". If the table caption is already 'Table 1-1' I want it to read:

```
Table 1-1 Intro Goals
```

after the macro runs, is that possible? How?

Comment: We need to know what effort into this. Did you research it? If so, why didn't it help? Did you write a macro? If not, why? Without evidence of effort it looks like you didn't try and want us to write the code for you, which is off-topic. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages.

Answer (score 1):

The script below is a batch process that does a find/replace routine on all the Word files in a folder.

```
Sub FindReplaceAll()
    Dim MyDialog As FileDialog, GetStr(1 To 100) As String 
'100 files is the maximum applying this code
    On Error Resume Next
Set MyDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With MyDialog
        .Filters.Clear
        .AllowMultiSelect = True
        i = 1
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each stiSelectedItem In .SelectedItems
                GetStr(i) = stiSelectedItem
                i = i + 1
            Next
            i = i - 1
        End If
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        For j = 1 To i Step 1
Set Doc = Documents.Open(FileName:=GetStr(j), Visible:=True)
Windows(GetStr(j)).Activate
            Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
            Selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
            With Selection.Find
                .Text = "Marriott International" 'Find What
                .Replacement.Text = "Marriott" 'Replace With
                .Forward = True
                .Wrap = wdFindAsk
                .Format = False
                .MatchCase = False
                .MatchWholeWord = False
                .MatchByte = True
                .MatchWildcards = False
                .MatchSoundsLike = False
                .MatchAllWordForms = False
            End With
            Selection.Find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
Application.Run macroname:="NEWMACROS"
ActiveDocument.Save
            ActiveWindow.Close
        Next
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    MsgBox "operation end, please view", vbInformation
End Sub
```

' The idea comes from here.

' https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/word/1002-word-replace-multiple-files.html